# Show/Hide View in xcode without leaving space

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout

1. I want to achieve this without adding height.
2. I tried using setHidden it works but leaves empty space.

is there any other way, after some googling i found that it is not possible?. i dont know may be .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to achieve this :

1) Use StackView with vertical orientation and add your views as arranged subviews in this stack view. Later you can remove the one you want and the height is adjusted automatically

2) Use constraints. Add a constraint from your 1st view to bottom with less priority initially. Later, when you call `setHidden()` on your second view, increase the priority of this constraint. In this way, the height will be adjusted.

You can try one the above approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `view.alpha = 0` as an alternate to change its opacity to 0, which would "hide" the view from sight but the view will be loaded for all intents and purposes.